# Function returning correct values individually but wrongly in a full on project

Tags: python, pandas

The below function returns wrong target values when run as part of my trading application. But when run separately in a different file, it gives correct value.

the function takes an order id, the direction of the trade and calls the orders for that day till its called.

```
trd_portfolio = {698627: {"Symbol": "USDINR20JULFUT", "max_quantity": 100, 'Direction': "", 'Orderid': 0, 'Target_order': '', 'Target_order_id': 0, 'Positions': 0, 'Tradable_quantity': 0, 'LTP': 0, 'Per_Unit_Cost': 1050}
                 }

profit[x] = ["Symbol", 0, 0, "Profit", 0, 0, 0]

def target(orderid, direction):
    global profit_Final, profit_temp
    try:
        day_profit = 0
        carry_forward = 0
        trade_profit = 0
        orders = kite.orders()
        for order in orders:
            price = order['average_price']
            print(price)
            symbol = order['tradingsymbol']
            print(symbol)
            type = order['transaction_type']
            print(type)
            token = order['instrument_token']
            print(token)
            volume = order['quantity'] * 1000
            print(volume)
            status = order['status']
            print(status)
            if type == 'BUY' and status == 'COMPLETE':
                profit[token][1] = price
            elif type == 'SELL' and status == 'COMPLETE':
                profit[token][2] = price
            profit[token][0] = symbol
            profit[token][4] = volume
            if (profit[token][1] != 0) & (profit[token][2] != 0):
                buy_brookerage = min((profit[token][1] * volume * 0.0003), 20)
                print(buy_brookerage)
                sell_brookerage = min((profit[token][2] * volume * 0.0003), 20)
                print(sell_brookerage)
                # stt_ctt = profit[token][2] * volume * 0.00025
                buy_tran = profit[token][1] * volume * 0.000009
                print(buy_tran)
                sell_tran = profit[token][2] * volume * 0.000009
                print(sell_tran)
                gst = (buy_brookerage + sell_brookerage + buy_tran + sell_tran) * 0.18
                print(gst)
                sebi_total = round((profit[token][1] + profit[token][2]) * volume * 0.000001, 0)
                print(sebi_total)
                stamp_charges = profit[token][1] * volume * 0.000001
                print(stamp_charges)
                profit[token][5] = sebi_total + gst + sell_tran + buy_tran + buy_brookerage + sell_brookerage + stamp_charges
                profit[token][3] = ((profit[token][2] - profit[token][1]) * volume) - profit[token][5]
                profit[token][6] = profit[token][3] - profit[token][5]
                profit_temp = pd.DataFrame([profit[token]],
                                           columns=["Symbol", "SELL Price", "BUY Price", "Profit", "Volume", "Charges",
                                                    "final_profit"])
                profit_Final = profit_Final.append(profit_temp)
                profit_Final.drop_duplicates(keep='first', inplace=True)
                profit[token][1] = 0
                profit[token][2] = 0
        print(profit_Final.to_string())
        for x in range(len(profit_Final)):
            carry_forward = carry_forward + profit_Final.iloc[-(x + 1), 6]
        print(carry_forward)

        Order_data = kite.order_history(orderid)
        for item in Order_data:
            if item['status'] == "COMPLETE":
                traded_price = item['average_price']
                print(traded_price)
                traded_quantity = item['quantity'] * 1000
                print(traded_quantity)
                Brokerage = min(((traded_price * traded_quantity) * 0.0003)*2, 40)
                print(Brokerage)
                # STT = (traded_price * traded_quantity) * (.03 / 100)
                TNXChrgs = ((traded_price * traded_quantity) * 2) * .000009
                print(TNXChrgs)
                GST = (Brokerage + TNXChrgs) * 0.18
                print(GST)
                SEBIChrgs = ((traded_price * 2) * traded_quantity) * 0.000001
                print(SEBIChrgs)
                StampDuty = ((traded_price * 2) * traded_quantity) * 0.000001
                print(StampDuty)
                order_charges = Brokerage + TNXChrgs + GST + SEBIChrgs + StampDuty
                print(order_charges)
                if carry_forward < 0:
                    target_amount = abs((order_charges * -2) + carry_forward) / traded_quantity
                    print(target_amount)
                else:
                    target_amount = abs(order_charges * 2)/traded_quantity
                    print(target_amount)
                if direction == "Up":
                    return ((traded_price + target_amount) - ((traded_price + target_amount) % .0025)) + 0.0025
                elif direction == "Down":
                    return (traded_price - target_amount) - ((traded_price - target_amount) % .0025)
    except Exception as e:
        traceback.print_exc()
        target(orderid, direction)

target(Orderid, direction)
```

here's a part of the orders i would get from the service provider.

```
[{'placed_by': '******', 'order_id': '20072800*******', 'exchange_order_id': '100000000*******', 'parent_order_id': None, 'status': 'COMPLETE', 'status_message': None, 'status_message_raw': None, 'order_timestamp': datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 28, 10, 25, 42), 'exchange_update_timestamp': '2020-07-28 10:25:42', 'exchange_timestamp': datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 28, 10, 25, 42), 'variety': 'regular', 'exchange': 'CDS', 'tradingsymbol': 'USDINR20JULFUT', 'instrument_token': 698627, 'order_type': 'MARKET', 'transaction_type': 'SELL', 'validity': 'DAY', 'product': 'MIS', 'quantity': 27, 'disclosed_quantity': 0, 'price': 0, 'trigger_price': 0, 'average_price': 74.805, 'filled_quantity': 27, 'pending_quantity': 0, 'cancelled_quantity': 0, 'market_protection': 0, 'meta': {}, 'tag': None, 'guid': '********'},
{'placed_by': '******', 'order_id': '20072800*******', 'exchange_order_id': '100000000*******', 'parent_order_id': None, 'status': 'COMPLETE', 'status_message': None, 'status_message_raw': None, 'order_timestamp': datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 28, 10, 37, 37), 'exchange_update_timestamp': '2020-07-28 10:37:37', 'exchange_timestamp': datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 28, 10, 37, 37), 'variety': 'regular', 'exchange': 'CDS', 'tradingsymbol': 'USDINR20JULFUT', 'instrument_token': 698627, 'order_type': 'MARKET', 'transaction_type': 'BUY', 'validity': 'DAY', 'product': 'MIS', 'quantity': 27, 'disclosed_quantity': 0, 'price': 0, 'trigger_price': 0, 'average_price': 74.825, 'filled_quantity': 27, 'pending_quantity': 0, 'cancelled_quantity': 0, 'market_protection': 0, 'meta': {}, 'tag': None, 'guid': '********'}]
```

the function goes through the order list, takes the traded values from each order, and when we have both sell and buy along with the volume, it does the charges and other calculations and returns a target price. But, while doing this calculations, it sometimes gets wrong sell and buy values and creates invalid entries into the profit dataframe when its called in the same .py file. But i did test it separately, only the target(), and it returned correct values over there.

Sorry to have posted such a long question and directly showing my code instead of asking the question in general sense. But i am learning python and having a hard time. I would have not shown the code if i knew any other way of getting the issue solved.

Comment: The main problem with your function is quite obvious: it's huge. You need to split it into smaller functions. Then test each function to make sure it works correctly by itself. Ideally, using unit tests. Then combine them in one runner function.

Comment: Hi @MikhailBeliansky. I tried the way you said and put this block of code in a separate module and called it when needed. But still the value was coming wrongly.